# GitHub Pages: How can I wrap text around an image?

Tags: github, github-pages, blogs, github-flavored-markdown

I have a GitHub blog page. Somewhere in the middle of the blog page, I have an image which is shown with the following Markdown content.

```
![My Image](pathto/myimage.png)
```

This works fine to display the image, but I also want to add a paragraph (wrapped to the right of the image) where I describe the image. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use `<img>` HTML tag with the `align` attribute in the Markdown content.

So instead of doing:

```
![My Image](pathto/myimage.png)
```

Write it as:

```
<img align="left" src="pathto/myimage.png" alt="My Image">
```

Align the image to the left, if you want the text to be on the right. If you want the text on the left, align the image to the right.

---

### Screenshots

*Markdown Text*

[image]

Markdown Preview

[image]