# How to write text on right of an image using GitHub markdown

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to write text on the right side of an image in GitHub .md file. I mean image should be displayed on the left side of the text (text including heading, list, para and links). I know I can do it using HTML or CSS using flex or so but is it possible to do it using GitHub markdown? And is it also possible for the text to be vertically aligned with respect to image size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown doesn't provide a set of rules or syntax for how the text is to be displayed, other than allowing HTML elements with CSS.  That's because Markdown, like HTML, is a markup language, and presentation is supposed to be done outside of it at a separate level (usually CSS).

However, for a variety of reasons, including security, aesthetics, and accessibility, GitHub strips out all CSS when it's rendering HTML from a README or other text document, so there isn't a way to do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the accepted answer is wrong. It is possible.

Github-Markdown:

```markdown
<img align="left" width="200" src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/25_Hilarious-Photos-that-Will-Get-You-Through-the-Week_280228817_Doty911.jpg" />

# Headline 

Some text
```

Rendered result on Github:
[image]

For the sake of completeness:
[image]

See also this answer: [GitHub Pages: How can I wrap text around an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69806697/github-pages-how-can-i-wrap-text-around-an-image)

Comment: Unfortunately, if the image is too high, and the text too short, almost all subsequent text in the markdown will be displayed at the right of the image... How do you force some sort of "new page"?